# Errors with Setting Username and Email Address in Git Using Windows Command Prompt

Tags: git, config, command-prompt

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am brand new to git and github, as well as the command line. In attempting to set my global username and email address in git, the following occurs:

(forgive the lack of formatting; I'm blind and styling is difficult. I will place the output in brackets.)

```
$ git config --global user.name "myName"
fatal: unable to access 'c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin c:\ProgramData\git\config/.config/git/config': Invalid argument

$ git config --global user.email "myEmail@email.com"
error: could not lock config file c:/programFiles/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I am confounded by these error messages. Apparently the computer is mistakenly identifying my jdk for the git config file, and I'm not sure why. 
I do have my home variable set to the path of my jdk, as I develop in java. The programData/git/config was my attempt to add this path to the home variable in hopes that it would fix the problem, clearly without success. The two error messages were identical before I added the second path to the home variable, but though I've now changed it back to how it was before, the error message for user.name is still different than that of user.email.

I am not extremely computer fluent yet, and am still trying to figure out how computer organization works. I'm not sure of what is going wrong here, and I'd appreciate an experienced eye.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing in Java does not need to set your `HOME` to your JDK path, you need to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK path (without the trailing `bin` BTW): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Try to reset your HOME to your actual home folder (`c:/Users/{YOUR_WINDOWS_LOGIN}` or something like that).